# How to get Oracle table query data into multiple excel sheets using SQL developer?

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oracle-sqldeveloper

Am using sqldeveloper 4.1.3.20 version

how to export oracle table query data into multiple excel sheets using sqldeveloper?

please let me know

i have 44lacks  records data

Comment: Version 4.1.3 is very old

Comment: If you use the export wizard you can export the contents of tables or views as separate sheets in your Excel file

Comment: I'm fascinated to know who's going to scroll through multiple worksheets in an Excel file of 4.4 million records.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

- run select statement
- right click on select result
- click export
- select format from drop down "excel"
- select save as "separate files"
- next stage
- finish

Comment: Why save as "separate files"? I doubt it actually makes any difference when exporting a result set to Excel, it's just an odd instruction to give.